# Writing a function in Python that returns a count of the numbers in an array that are greater than zero

Tags: python

For instance, lets say we call the function countPositive([1,2,3]), it will return a 3. Or if we have the array, [-1,0,1], there is one positive, so the function will return 1. So on, and so forth.

Comment: This is a very simple problem. You could have got the order just by using GOogle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def countPositive(nums):
    return len(filter(lambda x: x > 0, nums))
```

Some timeit results (on a new macbook air w/1.8 i7, 4 gigs, and cpython 2.7):

`filter` + `len`:

```
$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 100; len(filter(lambda x: x > 0, l))"  
  10000 loops, best of 3: 49.9 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 1000; len(filter(lambda x: x > 0, l))"                                                                  
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 10000; len(filter(lambda x: x >  0, l))" 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.86 msec per loop
```

`sum` (recommended by [hochl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949018/writing-a-function-in-python-that-returns-a-count-of-the-numbers-in-an-array-tha/7949035#7949035)):

```
$ python -m timeit "l = [1, 2, 3] * 100; sum(1 for x in l if x > 0)" 
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.1 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "l = [1, 2, 3] * 1000; sum(1 for x in l if x > 0)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 336 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "l = [1, 2, 3] * 10000; sum(1 for x in l if x > 0)"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.4 msec per loop
```

So the `sum` version is slightly faster, but I think the `len` + `filter` is more readable.

Comment: The lists in the two tests are different, [-1, 0, 1] vs [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 8):

```
def countPositive(nums):
        return sum(1 for x in nums if x > 0)
```

Comment: indeed we have the same idea ;-) I didn't notice yours at first, I'll delete mine and send an upvote your way.

Comment: Hey why delete yours ... both are valid. I'd upvote yours as well :-)

Comment: Much appreciated, but goodness knows I have enough rep already and IMO there's not much point having two separate answers which say the exact same thing :-P

Comment: Note that this can be written as `sum(x > 0 for x in nums)`. Python's `bool`s are really just the integers 1 and 0 with nicer string representations. @helloimbarbara: That's an entirely different question, so you should (if you really can't solve it yourself) ask it seperately.

Comment: @delnan: nice idea ... but less obvious when you read such code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    greaterThanZero = 0
    for i in array:
        if i > 0:
             greaterThanZero += 1

    return greaterThanZero
```

Comment: `for i in range array.length:`? You mean `for i in array`?

Comment: that's exactly what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def countPositive(array):
  count=0
  for i in array: 
    if i>0: 
      count = count +1
  return count
```

Comment: Why a negative vote? Maybe he doesn't want to use the most complicated feature even, especially if he asks that kind of question!

Comment: I didn't downvote anything, someone else did. And I'm not a he, I'm a she.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, list comprehension is the fastest:

```
$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 10000; len([n for n in l if n > 0])"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 msec per loop
```

Using sum: (slower)

```
$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 10000; sum(1 for x in l if x > 0)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 msec per loop
```

Using filter: (slowest)

```
$ python -m timeit "l = [-1, 0, 1] * 10000; len(filter(lambda x: x >  0, l))" 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+int(y>0),[1, 2, 1, 4,5],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works too:

```
function countMoreThanZero(a):

    for i in a:

        if i > 0:

            sum += 1

    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a lambda

```
from operator import lt
from functools import partial

def count_positive(nums):
    return len(filter(partial(lt, 0), nums))
```

Should be quicker because it avoids the lambda.